# Creating a new numpy array with modified element data type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I had expected the following to create a new numpy array from the shape of an existing array but with modified element data type. My original array is an image with 8bit RGB pixels. I want to create a new array using same shape but with uint16 data type. The purpose is then to convert the image into 16bit pixels and perform some math. To my surprise the following didn't work.

```
>>> import scipy.misc        as msc
>>> import numpy             as np
>>> img_rgb = msc.imread('Jupiter_20160417_53.png')
>>> img_rgb.dtype
dtype('uint8')
>>> img_rgb.shape
(480, 640, 3)
>>> new= np.zeros(img_rgb.shape,dtype=uint16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'uint16' is not defined
```

What did I miss?

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: >>> a  = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=np.uint16) works for me (import numpy as np  of course)

Answer (score 1):

The `np.`:

```
In [2]: np.zeros((3,4),dtype=np.uint16)
Out[2]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

`'uint16'` (the string) would have worked as well.

`int` and `float` are Python names; almost all the other `dtypes` are `numpy` specific, and require either the `np.` namespace or a string name (which `numpy` understands).

The error `NameError: name 'uint16' is not defined` means that `uint16` is not a variable in the main namespace.  In other words it's not a builtin variable (or function), and it hasn't been imported as such.  It is part of the `numpy` namespace which you imported a `np`.

e.g.

```
In [8]: z
...
NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you hpaulj. The 'np.' prefix worked. What is the better code style?  np.zeros((3,4),dtype='uint16')  or  np.zeros((3,4),dtype=np.uint16) ?

Comment: I don't think it matters.  More details here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't it work for me, np.uint8 does, but on np.uint16 CV throws an exception that Assertion failed in cvShowImage